# Make file Error when listing Dir Contents

Tags: file, makefile

When I try to list all the contents of a directory (to use later as a dependency) it gives this error at the end of the listing (my permissions are not the problem):

gmake: execvp: filename: Permission denied
gmake: ***[test] Error 127

I don't quite understand this, the file is the first in the directory and is fine until the end of the listing, this does list all the files. I ran gmake -n to see if its trying to execute and it does not for this target. Sorry if I speak incorrectly, this is my first try at a complex make file.

Here is my code:

test:
       $(wildcard $(MY_DIR)/*.cpp)

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is, but we can narrow it down. Try looking for files in the current directory (`test: $(wildcard *.cpp)`). Try looking for a specific file (`test: $(wildcard $(MY_DIR)/foo.cpp)`). Try removing all the `.cpp` files from that directory and see what happens, and if that works put one back and try again.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it from the current directory and get the same results, its always on the first file listed too.

Comment: That narrows it down. What version of Make are you using (`make -v`)?

Comment: GNU Make 3.81 (c) 2006

Comment: I'm using the same version and can't reproduce your error. What's the name of the file?

Comment: It doesn't seem to matter what the name of the file is. But they are anything from .h to .cpp files. Maybe its the overall structure of my Make file?

Answer (score 1):

Now I *have* to find out what's going on. Time for some more experiments. With one `.cpp` file in the working directory, call it `foo.cpp`, and this makefile:

```
SRC := $(wildcard *.cpp) 

$(info SRC is $(SRC))

test1: foo.cpp
    @echo $@ sees $^
```

try `make`, and tell us the result.

Comment: Sorry I will run this in a bit and post the results, I'm knee deep on a bigger problem. Thank you so much so far.

Comment: I'm trying to add this, but I'm not sure I quite understand what going on. test1: foo.cpp is this calling another target? And this $(info SRC is $(SRC)), where should this be? Thanks